# How to show the existence of a Bellman Equation Solution?

Tags: dynamical-systems, self-learning, economics, dynamic-programming

consider the Bellman Equation

\begin{equation*}
V(\alpha)=\max_{\beta} f(\beta,\alpha)+A(\beta,\alpha) V(\alpha)+B(\beta,\alpha) V'(\alpha)
\end{equation*}

How can I show the existence of the solution? I tried to translate it into an Optimal Control one and use Pontryagin, but I don't think I can do so...

Comment: Doesn't the existence depend on $f,A,B$? If $B \equiv 0, A \equiv 1$, then it equivalently asks for $V(\alpha) = \max_\beta f(\beta,\alpha) + V(\alpha)$ which need not have a solution in $V$. Do you have certain assumptions here?